# Why cursor pointer size not getting small on Mac OS X sierra?

Tags: mac, macos, mouse, cursor

I'm using Logitech mouse with my Mac OS X sierra, the issue is when I'm changing the cursor pointer size, making it small, it's not appearing. Only big pointer can be seen not the small one. Can anyone help me about this?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Could you add more info about your issue or, perhaps, some screenshots?

Comment: please take a look at the cursor pointer! few screenshot attached. If i try to make the cursor size small, it totally disappears!!! 
http://res.cloudinary.com/dqe9csqry/image/upload/v1498144591/Screen_Shot_2017-06-22_at_8.41.32_PM_ahkwld.png
http://res.cloudinary.com/dqe9csqry/image/upload/v1498144591/Screen_Shot_2017-06-22_at_8.41.37_PM_tvgjea.png
http://res.cloudinary.com/dqe9csqry/image/upload/v1498144591/Screen_Shot_2017-06-22_at_8.41.23_PM_xqckz8.png

Comment: Can you elaborate how you are "changing the cursor size"?

Comment: Did you try to connect some other mouse instead of your Logitech?

Comment: Do you have betterTouchTool installed? That has options which mess with cursor size.

Answer (score 3):

Please try going to System Preferences->Accesssibility->Display:

[image: Slide the Cursor size knob]

Slide the Cursor size knob towards Normal. Does your cursor change size while you are sliding it? If so you can make it smaller that way.

Also, is it possible you have zoomed in or out on the screen itself?

Go to System Preferences->Accessibility->Zoom:

[image]

Try turning on Use keyboard shortcuts to zoom, and then use Zoom out to zoom all the way to the normal setting, where you cannot zoom out further.

Comment: Yes, already tried that! During moving the knob to "Normal", nearly half the slider the cursor totally disappears! Any thoughts?